# Having trouble installing pip for Windows 10 on python 2.7

Tags: python, pip

I have had lots of trouble downloading pip. I went and download the get-pip.py. I saved it to my desktop and ran the file. A window appeared for about 1.5 seconds and then disappears. I then tried to run the file through the python command line, I gave the command "python get-pip.py" and then I got:

Error:

```
python get-pip.py
File "<stdin>", line 1
python get-pip.py
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried adding python to my path and ran the file again and I got the same response. I am very lost and was wondering if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct version of pip? It's hard to figure out without more information, but you could be using the python 3 version of pip.

Easiest way: Install py2.7.9 with pip included.

https://docs.python.org/2/installing/